# SharePoint Timer Service acting erratically

Tags: timer-jobs, timer-service

This is a SharePoint 2010 Server Enterprise Install with SP1 and the December 2011 CU.
The farm has 1 WFE/App server and 1 DB server.

My timer service restarts constantly.  I see this message in the event log every minute:

SharePoint Web Services Round Robin Service Load Balancer Event: Initialization
Process Name: OWSTIMER
Process ID: 9556
AppDomain Name: DefaultDomain
AppDomain ID: 1
Service Application Uri: urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:service:946622d2b919416284c9b20f6beacdeb#authority=urn:uuid:33cb3a0999374d1fb1817805066dd798&authority=https://{server}:32844/Topology/topology.svc
Active Endpoints: 1
Failed Endpoints:0
Endpoint List:
http://{Server}:32843/946622d2b919416284c9b20f6beacdeb/WebAnalyticsService.svc

Although this one specifies WebAnalyticsService.svc, it happens consistently with the endpoint of MetadataWebService.svc, ProfileService.svc, etc.  I do not have SSL but I notice there is an https in the error.  I'm not sure if that is related. Last night the timer service hung up and stopped processing timer jobs.  The status of the Service in services.msc was 'Started' but I could not restart it without first killing the process.  The following error occurs pretty frequently (6-12 times a day):

Faulting application OWSTIMER.EXE, version 14.0.6114.5000, time stamp 0x4ec44de1, faulting module kernel32.dll, version 6.0.6002.18005, time stamp 0x49e041d1, exception code 0xe0434f4d, fault offset 0x00000000000176fd, process id 0x11a4, application start time 0x01cd53f7bf0d22b7.

What could cause my timer service to act so erratically?

Comment: Can you share the topology of your farm ?

Comment: and can you share the version of sharepoint your using as well please

Comment: I have one WFE/App and one DB.
SharePoint 2010 with SP1 and Dec 2011 CU

Comment: is it something just started happening , as there were few updates released by Microsoft for windows Server few days back.

Comment: I have not updated Windows since this problem began.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Managed Metadata Service or User Profile Service was causing the Timer Service to restart every minute.  I stopped the Managed Metadata Service, User Profile Sync Service and User Profile Service.  When I restarted the services, the Timer Service returned to normal.

Answer (score 0):

seems like your running the Backup timer job when the timer job has been scheduled. 
Please deleted  the failed Backup/Restore timer job in Central Administrator site, and check if it helps.

[this link might help:](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/be9fddf5-b8b5-45f5-abcc-ab1678f8bebc/)

or check this Link out

[The Timer Recycle Job](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/besidethepoint/archive/2012/01/10/the-timer-recycle-job-job-timer-recycle.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have no failed backups and my timer recycle job is set at a daily schedule.